# toggling between output and command prompt in CentOS terminal

Tags: centos, terminal

When I open the `terminal` in `CentOS linux` and use `su -` to work as the `root` user, I type in commands like `journalctl` that result in a lot of output.  The problem is, when I am done scrolling through the many lines of output, `terminal` just tells me the line number and does not give me an obvious way to get another command prompt.  **How can I get a command prompt back in this situation without having to open a new terminal?**

Comment: Don't you have a ':' as prompt at the end?

Comment: I thought the output might have been piped through `less`. I would try Ctrl-D and Ctrl-C.

Comment: @Anthon `Ctrl-D` takes me to the end.  Then `Ctrl-C` gives the the command prompt.  If you want to submit that as an answer, I will mark it as accepted and +1.  Thank you.

Comment: If the problem is that you've scrolled up and now want to get back to the bottom just type something. Most terminals will automatically scroll back down to the prompt at that point.

Comment: Ah, then you are in a pager of some sort. Possibly `less` or `more`. Try hitting `q`.

Comment: If this was less I would expect `ctrl-d` to scroll down half a page not all the way to the end but it might be something else I suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe typing "q", whether at the end or not, will return you to your console. Is this not the case on your machine?

Edit: at least, less and journalctl behave this way for me on fedora 20.

Comment: Thank you.  Please see comments above from Anthon and EtanReisner who gave this and more detail earlier.

Comment: Sorry about that, I didn't see that Etan beat me by fifteen minutes. I had the answer prepared but typed it up too late.